# How to sum in a for loop in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, iteration

I am the beginner in pandas and am struggling with a for loop.

I loaded the following excel file to pandas:

```
x=pd.read_excel('BTC.xlsx',)
x
```

Here is what I get:

```
   BTC obtained
0   0.00567
1   0.00054
2   0.00230
```

I want to iterate the numbers using a for loop:

```
n=0
for v in x.iteritems():
    n+=v
    print(n)
```

When I run this, I always get the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Comment: I'm guessing you're getting the error on the for loop. iteritems() takes two arguments, not just the single v. Please see the documentation at https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html

Comment: Yes you are right. But I want to get the following as a result: 0.00567, 0.00621 (0.00567+0.00054) and 0.00851 (0.00621+0.00230).

Answer (score 1):

If you see the documentation of [iteritems](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iteritems.html), you will see that the command yields two things:

- label: object
- content: Series

That means that v will be a tuple (label, content). If you want to access the series you will have to access v[1].

Alternatively, you can do:

> for label, v in x.iteritems():

Based on your comment, it seems like you want the cumulative summation of the elements. You can do this without a for loop, by using pandas [cumsum](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.cumsum.html):

```
n = x.cumsum()
```

If you want to use a for loop you can do the following:

```
n=0  
for label, v in x.iteritems():  
    n+=v['BTC obtained']  
    print(n)
```

Comment: A great explanation! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use iterrows() for this like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'BTC obtained':[0.00567,0.00054,0.00230]})
print(df)

n=0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    n+=row["BTC obtained"]
    print(n)
```

Output

```
0.00567
0.006209999999999999
0.00851
```

Comment: That is correct! It works. Thank you very much Sir!